# Show that $\frac{x-1}{y-1} \leq \frac{x}{y}$

Tags: proof-explanation

i assume that this is very simple, but i cannot figure out a solution.

can somebody give a proof for
$$\frac{x-1}{y-1} \leq \frac{x}{y}$$
given that $$ x \leq y$$
and
$$ x \gt 1$$

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y\ge x,x>1$, you have $y-1>0$. So
$$ \frac{x-1}{y-1}-\frac{x}{y}=\frac{(x-1)y-x(y-1)}{y(y-1)}=\frac{x-y}{y(y-1)} \le 0$$
namely
$$ \frac{x-1}{y-1}\le\frac{x}{y}. $$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
x &\le y\\
xy+x &\le xy+y\\
xy-y &\le xy-x\\
y(x-1) &\le x(y-1)\\
\frac {x-1}{y-1} &\le \frac xy
\end{align}

Dividing by $y(y-1)$ in the last step maintains the inequality as $y \ge x \gt 1>0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$F=\dfrac xy-\dfrac{x-1}{y-1}=\dfrac{x(y-1)-(x-1)y}{y(y-1)}=\dfrac{y-x}{y(y-1)}$$

What if $F=0?$

$F$ will be $>0$

if even number of terms in $y,y-1,y-x$ are $<0$

If none of those are $<0,y\in[1,0,x]$ or $y>$max$(0,1,x)$

If two of those are $<0,$

If $y<0$ or $y>1,y(y-1)>0\implies y-x>0$

If $0<y<1,y(y-1)<0$ and $y-x<0$

Answer (score 0):

$xy = xy$;

$xy -y \le xy -x$, since $x \le y$

$y(x-1)\le x(y-1)$;

$\dfrac{x-1}{y-1} \le \dfrac{x}{y}$, since $y \ge x >1$.